# How to generate debug information in gcc/clang with separated compilation/link process in Makefile (-c -g)?

Tags: macos, gcc, makefile, clang, dsym

I had made a Makefile from Hilton Lipschitz's [blog](http://hiltmon.com/blog/2015/09/28/the-simple-c-plus-plus-makefile-executable-edition/), and made little changes to it in order to generate debug information. Main parts are listed:

```
CC := clang -arch x86_64
CFLAGS := -c -O0

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    @echo "  Linking $(TARGET)"; $(CC) $^ -o $(TARGET) $(LIB)

$(BUILDDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.$(SRCEXT)
    @mkdir -p $(BUILDLIST)
    @echo "Compiling $<..."; $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INC) -o $@ $<

debug: CFLAGS += -g
debug: $(TARGET)
```

Now `make` runs these commands (paths are summarized with `...`):

```
clang -arch x86_64 -c -O0 -I... -o build/program.o src/program.c
clang -arch x86_64 build/program.o -o bin/program -L...
```

While `make debug` runs these commands:

```
clang -arch x86_64 -c -O0 -g -I... -o build/program.o src/program.c
clang -arch x86_64 build/program.o -o bin/program -L...
```

The problem is when I execute `make` or `make debug`, no `program.dSYM` subfolder will be made in `bin` folder. Instead, when I compile without `-c` argument:

```
clang -arch x86_64 -g -O0 -I... -L... -o bin/program.o src/program.c
```

both executable file and `.dSYM` are created in `bin` folder.

1. How can I add debugging information generation feature to this Makefile while separating compiling and linking process?
2. In which step (compiling/linking) debug information is produced?

**UPDATE**: I created a GitHub [repo](https://github.com/hamid914/gdb-lldb-test) and uploaded related Makefile and source to it. To reproduce the problem, please run these commands in your terminal:

```
git clone https://github.com/hamid914/gdb-lldb-test.git
cd gdb-lldb-test
make debug
```

The last line, `make debug` executes these commands:

```
clang -arch x86_64 -c -O0 -std=c11 -g -I include -I include/libs -I /usr/local/include -o build/program.o src/program.c
clang -arch x86_64 build/program.o -o bin/program -L /usr/local/lib -lm -g
```

And content of `bin` folder is:

```
$ ls bin
program
```

While if I run `clang` without `-c` argument:

```
clang -arch x86_64 -O0 -std=c11 -g -I include -I include/libs -I /usr/local/include -L /usr/local/lib -lm -o bin/program src/program.c
```

Contents of `bin` folder are:

```
$ ls bin
program      program.dSYM
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to add `-g` to the linker recipe as well in order to generate .dSYM files, the standard way would be to add

```
debug: LDFLAGS += -g
```

but the example you're following defines its own variables for no good reason, it looks like `LIB` should work however.

Comment: Adding `-g` flag to the linker will not generate .dSYM files. I tried to add `-g` to the both compiler and linker, but the result is the same.

Comment: @HamidRohani Add a self-contained example to your question, it works fine for me.